# SQL Joining and Replacing spaces with NA

Tags: sql

I am trying to join two `SQL` queries

for example

- Table1 have Empname ,Empcode
- Table2 have Empname,Empcode,Empsalary

I am trying to get the name and salaries details wherever there no salary then it have to reflect as "NA"

My Query is:

```
select a.Empname,if((Empsalary=" "),"NA",b.salary) as salary
from
(select Empname,empcode from Table 1) as a
inner join all
(select Empcode,Empsalary from Table 2) as b
on a.empcode=b.empcode
```

Is this Query correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  a.Empname,
  CASE 
    WHEN b.Empsalary = '' OR b.Empsalary IS NULL THEN 'NA' 
    ELSE b.Empsalary 
  END as salary
from Table 1 as a
inner join Table 2 as b on a.empcode = b.empcode
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use;

```
ISNULL(field_name, 'NA')
```

Comment: i think .. it's `nvl()` function

Comment: when you use oracle then yes it is nvl()

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better variant of what Mahmoud Gamal posted is this one with `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` on the column, so if the line has a *`space`* in the salary column it is eliminated. `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` removes left and right white spaces from a string.

You'd use this to be sure you're always comparing the same thing, because a '' is different from a ' '.

```
select 
  a.Empname,
  CASE 
    WHEN LTRIM(RTRIMb.Empsalary)) = '' OR b.Empsalary IS NULL THEN 'NA' 
    ELSE b.Empsalary 
  END as salary
from Table 1 as a
inner join Table 2 as b on a.empcode = b.empcode
```

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL is a dialect specific operator; COALESCE is the ANSI version (works the same but can have more than two parameters and returns the first that isn't null).

Answer (score 0):

Is a left-join appropriate given you might have an emp but no entry (rather than just a null salary in table 2)

```
SELECT t1.Empname, t1. Empcode, COALESCE(t2.Empsalary, 'NA')
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 
  ON t1.EmpCode = t2.EmpCode
```